# Story where Geralt needed help from a werewolf to infiltrate an enemy’s lair

Tags: story-identification, books, the-witcher

For some reason I remember a story about Geralt of *The Witcher* series infiltrating an enemy’s hideout and needing the help of a werewolf to do it.

In this story while looking for the entrance to the hideout on a mountain, they stumble across the den of a monster that both Geralt and the werewolf desperately know they don’t want to wake up, so they pass by without disturbing it. Later on in the story, once Geralt has entered the lair and let the werewolf return home, the werewolf returns to help Geralt at a pivotal moment.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  I've modified your question a bit to be a clear story-identification question.  You might want to check out our [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) for writing good story-id questions, in case they help you remember anything else.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That would be in *Season of Storms*, chapter 17, where Geralt asks Otto Dussart, a werewolf, for help, not as much to infiltrate, but to find the lair:

> ‘Not really. I don’t want to offend you, Witcher, but the smell of blood carries off you.’
>
> ‘I’ve not touched blood in…’
>
> ‘Nearly two weeks, I would say,’ finished the werewolf. ‘This blood is old, you touched someone bloody. There is an older blood there as well, somewhere around a month. Cold blood. Reptile blood. Your blood as well. Live blood from a wound.’
>
> ‘Amazing.’
>
> ‘We werewolves,’ said Dussart proudly, ‘have a nose, a little bit more sensitive than humans.’
>
> ‘I know,’ smiled Geralt. ‘I know about werewolves’ noses – a true wonder of nature. That is why I’ve come to ask this favour of you.’

And then he comes for help:

> The hunchback roared and raised the crossbow.
>
> But he did not get time to shoot.
>
> Into the cavern, like a grey arrow, burst a huge wolf. He hit the hunchback in the legs and back, tearing ligaments and arteries. The hunchback cried out and fell. The fallen crossbow’s bowstring clicked. Bue wheezed. A bolt went into his ear. The tip of it poking out of the other ear.
>
> The hunchback howled. The wolf opened its terrible maw and grabbed his head. The howl turned into a croak.

All English texts are from the fan translation.

Comment: That’s it! I had a feeling it was that book as that’s the only one I haven’t been able to find a good synopsis for online. I only ever listened to it as an audiobook, which obviously doesn’t lend itself to quick perusal. Thanks so much for identifying that for me!

Comment: @martin122089 No problem! I think it was published in Polish around 2013, hence no official English translation (that I know of, at least) yet.